# html5/canvas/js component/chart for time data visualization that support both client-side zoom and server-side downsampling

Tags: javascript, charts

I search for html5/canvas/js chart component for time data visualization that support both client-side zoom and server-side downsampling

I mean JS widget that provides API to handle zoom event and request new data.

jquery/vanilla-js/webcomponent based.

Comment: Are you asking for server-side downsampling software too? Or will you do it yourself?

Comment: Thank you for your question! I could do downsampling by myself. But that is a good idea to search/ask for downsampling library that could be used for.net core. Here I search just for a control/widget that provides api to handle "zoom" event server-side.

Comment: Please edit to add this to your question, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Essential Chart EJ 2 for JavaScript](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/chart) supports creating charts for time based data. Down sampling is also supported as shown in the [example](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/chart/how-to/down-sampling).

[image: Essential Chart Downsampling]

Zooming support is also built into the Chart.

[image: Essential Chart Zooming]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.